# div float right does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I have to place two divs in a single line , one div to the left and other to the right.
Below is the code i used.

```
var sendDate = document.createElement('div');
sendDate.style.width = "40%";
sendDate.style.cssFloat = "left";

var dueDate = document.createElement('div');
dueDate.style.width = "40%";
dueDate.style.cssFloat = "right";
```

But this works fine in FF and Chrome , but not in IE.
In IE , the duedate comes below the senddate instead of aligning to the right of senddate.
I have spent enough time trying to find a solution but no luck. I tried to clear the float of senddate as well but it dint work.
Please let me know how to achieve this in IE.

TIA...

Comment: MDN says: For IE 8 and older it is `style.styleFloat`  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/float)

Comment: Why not just using style.float = "left" ? This works under ie7

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

CSS

```
.left { float:left; }
.right { float:right; }
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
var sendDate = document.createElement('div');
sendDate.style.width = "40%";
sendDate.className = "left";
```

Or use [jquery](http://jquery.com/) which will manage your browser compatibility

Comment: Thanks all for the prompt response.

Comment: I used style.styleFloat for IE since i am defining styles in the js itself instead of in CSS and it worked.